# Converting multiple same key object in single object within array json

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, loops

I have this `json` below:

```
[
  {"animal": "cat"},
  {"animal": "dog"},
  {"animal": "elephant"},
  {"vehicle": "car"},
  {"vehicle": "bike"},
  {"vehicle": "truck"},
  {"toys": "a1"},
  {"toys": "a2"},
  {"toys": "a3"}
]
```

My expected json response is:

```
[
  {"animal": "cat", "vechile": "car", "toys": "a1"},
  {"animal": "dog", "vechile": "bike", "toys": "a2"},
  {"animal": "elephant", "vechile": "truck", "toys": "a3"}
]
```

I tried the following program but didn't give me the expected output, I wanted to make an array where I could compare it and add accordingly:

```
var myGlobalArr = []
var globalObject = {}

for (var i = 0; i < mainArr.length; i++)
{
    if (Object.keys(mainArr[i])[0] == Object.keys(myGlobalArr[i])[0])
    {
        globalObject[Object.keys(mainArr[i])[0]] = globalObject[Object.values(mainArr[i])[0]]
    }
}

console.log(myGlobalArr)
```

**HELP WOULD BE APPRECIATED!!**

**#EDITED:**

It is going to be block of `3`.

Comment: what is the rule to link the elements? Is it always blocks of 3 ?

Comment: Yep!... It is always to be 3.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using [Array.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce). On every iteration of `reduce` you can check to what index of the final array put your data using the current index of the object `modulus` 3 (`idx % 3`):

```js
const input = [
  {"animal": "cat"},
  {"animal": "dog"},
  {"animal": "elephant"},
  {"vehicle": "car"},
  {"vehicle": "bike"},
  {"vehicle": "truck"},
  {"toys": "a1"},
  {"toys": "a2"},
  {"toys": "a3"}
];

let res = input.reduce((acc, curr, idx) =>
{
    let [[k, v]] = Object.entries(curr);
    acc[idx % 3] = acc[idx % 3] || {};
    acc[idx % 3][k] = v;
    return acc;
}, [])

console.log(res);
```

```css
.as-console {background-color:black !important; color:lime;}
.as-console-wrapper {max-height:100% !important; top:0;}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could take a hash table which takes care of the right index of the same key for the result set.

This works for an arbitrary count of objects/properties and order, as long as the same properties are in order.

```js
var data = [ { animal: "cat" }, { animal: "dog" }, { animal: "elephant" }, { vehicle: "car" }, { vehicle: "bike" }, { vehicle: "truck" }, { toys: "a1" }, { toys: "a2" }, { toys: "a3" }],
    indices = {},
    result = data.reduce((r, o) => {
        var key = Object.keys(o)[0];
        indices[key] = indices[key] || 0;
        Object.assign(r[indices[key]] = r[indices[key]] || {}, o);
        indices[key]++;
        return r;
    }, []);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```